# Optimization: Accessing fields vs. methods

Tags: android, optimization, class-design

I know rule #1 of optimization is: don't do it! But I figured this was an easy question, and if I start using the faster method now I can save a lot of cpu time when I'm finished.

I'm making an RPG, and let's say this is part of a custom class:

```
public class Baddie{

    int health;
    int magic;

    public Baddie(int health, int magic){
        this.health = health;
        this.magic = magic;
    }

    public int getHealth(){
        return health;
    }
```

Now, the answer to my question may be "there's no difference" and that's fine with me.. I just want to know. Is it quicker to get the Baddie's health using field access:

```
//Somewhere in the main thread, I get an instance of Baddie..
Baddie b = getScaryBadGuy();
int baddieHealth = b.health;
```

Or is it quicker to use a return method?

```
int baddieHealth = b.getHealth();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copied and pasted from [Designing for Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html):

> > **Avoid Internal Getters/Setters**
>
> In native languages like C++ it's
> common practice to use getters (e.g. i
> = getCount()) instead of accessing the field directly (i = mCount). This is
> an excellent habit for C++, because
> the compiler can usually inline the
> access, and if you need to restrict or
> debug field access you can add the
> code at any time.
>
> On Android, this is a bad idea.
> Virtual method calls are expensive,
> much more so than instance field
> lookups. It's reasonable to follow
> common object-oriented programming
> practices and have getters and setters
> in the public interface, but within a
> class you should always access fields
> directly.
>
> Without a JIT, direct field access is
> about 3x faster than invoking a
> trivial getter. With the JIT (where
> direct field access is as cheap as
> accessing a local), direct field
> access is about 7x faster than
> invoking a trivial getter. This is
> true in Froyo, but will improve in the
> future when the JIT inlines getter
> methods.

Comment: Oh! I thought I read that thoroughly.. guess not! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Performance is always relative. It's usually better to think in terms of percentages or factors. If something takes a microsecond, maybe that's a lot, and maybe it's nothing. It depends on how many times per second you need to do it. That's the main reason premature optimization is frowned upon, it is done without knowing if there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will optimize if it can. This is a perfect example of premature optimization. use whatever makes sense in your code. Don't worry about "saving cycles". The 2-3 cycles this may or may not save is outweighed by the millions of cycles it takes for any other operation.

Comment: Although the answer says to use field access, I'm sure you're right as well. It is kind of a trivial question, I guess. It's not like phones nowadays can't handle a few methods :P I'll try not to worry about optimization.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's more a design question than optimization question. I would suggest not writing/generating any getter or setter until you actually need them to be accessed from outside of your class. This tends to keep coupling as low as possible.

Alternatively making those getters/setters private by default would have the same result but it's more code for no real benefit.